# Updating values in gridview is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

There is a row in `gridview` in which there is a column name as `POA_NO` whose value is `899`.

But I am deleting that value and updating it as blank. But still it is getting updated as `899` only.

Here is my code

```
protected void GrdDetail_UpdateCommand(object sender, GridRecordEventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["ViewInfo"] != null)
    {
        dtViewInfo = (DataTable)Session["ViewInfo"];
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

    DataRow[] drViewInfo = dtViewInfo.Select("SR_NO = " + e.Record["SR_NO"]);

    if (e.Record["TYPE"] != "")
    {
        drViewInfo[0]["TYPE"] = e.Record["TYPE"];
    }
    else
    {
        drViewInfo[0]["TYPE"] = "NULL";
    }

    if (e.Record["REF_NO"] != "")
    {
        drViewInfo[0]["REF_NO"] = e.Record["REF_NO"];
    }
    if (e.Record["REF_DATE"] != "")
    {
        drViewInfo[0]["REF_DATE"] = e.Record["REF_DATE"];
    }
    if (e.Record["POA_NO"] != "")
    {
        drViewInfo[0]["POA_NO"] = e.Record["POA_NO"];
    }
    if (e.Record["POA_DATE"] != "")
    {
        drViewInfo[0]["POA_DATE"] = e.Record["POA_DATE"];
    }
    if (e.Record["POA_NAME"] != "")
    {
        drViewInfo[0]["POA_NAME"] = e.Record["POA_NAME"];
    }

    if (e.Record["ATTACHMENT"] != "")
    {
        drViewInfo[0]["ATTACHMENT"] = e.Record["ATTACHMENT"];
    }

    GrdDetail.DataSource = dtViewInfo;
    GrdDetail.DataBind();
    AddToViewState("GridViewInfo");
}
```

**EDIT**

Page load code

```
dtViewInfo = CF.ExecuteDT("select sr_no, type, ref_no, to_char (ref_date,'dd/MM/yyyy') ref_date, POA_NO , to_char (POA_DATE, 'dd/MM/yyyy')   POA_DATE, POA_NAME, attachment from xxcus.XXACL_PN_VIEW_DATA_INFO " +
                              "where mkey = '" + StrMkey + "' order by   sr_no");


    GrdDetail.DataSource = dtViewInfo;
    GrdDetail.DataBind();
    AddToViewState("GridViewInfo");
```

Comment: Maybe the error is to ask if (e.Record["POA_NO"] != "") ? Let it out, write simple drViewInfo[0]["POA_NO"] = e.Record["POA_NO"];

Comment: @duDE: so should I need to check for blank too ?

Comment: use dtViewInfo.AcceptChanges() at the end before databind

Comment: @SouvikGhosh: let me try and check

Comment: @SouvikGhosh: it still shows me `899`.

Comment: Did you put it before this line- 'GrdDetail.DataSource = dtViewInfo;' ?

Comment: @duDE: with your code, I get error as **Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <> in POA_NO Column.  Expected type is Decimal.**

Comment: @SouvikGhosh: Nope, I added like this `GrdDetail.DataSource = dtViewInfo;
        dtViewInfo.AcceptChanges();
        GrdDetail.DataBind();`

Comment: Please change it to 'dtViewInfo.AcceptChanges(); GrdDetail.DataSource = dtViewInfo; GrdDetail.DataBind();'. Also please check (in debug mode) that dtViewInfo has the updated data at the end before binding.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh: tried that too, still it is coming as `899`

Comment: can you show me your code in page load event ?

Comment: @RonakPatel: updated the question

Comment: Are you using IsPostback function in Load event ?

Comment: @RonakPatel: yes, now updated the page load code for you. earlier was wrong one